# What is these mushrooms in my indoor pot?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I am living in Japan and in summer, it's very hot and humid even inside my room.
Today, I've found two mushrooms in the pot of a plant.

What is this species? It's very surprising than within one day they grew like this.

[image: Mushrooms' picture]

Comment: Looks like *Lepiota sp.*

Comment: @RHA Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: @kmm It's not an answer but a suggestion.

Comment: Suggestion: If you leave them and the cap turns to black slime .they are comatus coprinis, shaggy mane.  Good to eat ( the next crop).

Comment: Note: regardless of the expertise of anyone here, do NOT try to eat anything you have identified by someone on the internet.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I'm not gonna eat anything. It's maybe edible in the wood but inside in a pot I've put some unknown fertilizers.. don't wanna try haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do look a lot like a common mushroom called "shaggy mane" mushroom (Coprinus comatus). This may not be a correct identification though, so do not eat them.  They are widespread around the world, but usually grow outside.

Yes it is amazing how rapidly the fruiting body of many fungi can grow. I am providing an interesting Wikipedia link with more information. You can also search to find other images using Google images online.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprinus_comatus